# Modal windows in the background?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a fresh installation (from today) of Linux Mint 21.3 with all upgrades done.  I also have installed Visual Studio Code:

```
Version: 1.87.2
Commit: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
Date: 2024-03-08T15:14:59.643Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.15.0-101-generic
```

Now, I have a most peculiar problem where a modal window that gets created to, for example save a file for the first time, does not appear on top of the main IDE window.  It appears behind.  I noticed because on the task bar the icon for VSCode gets decorated with a 2 by way of a superscript and from there it is easy to switch to the the other window to complete the task.

I tried the equivalent operation in LibreOffice and over there the modal window to save files appears on top of the main window.  This is clearly a problem affecting VSCode. I never thought that the application itself could control where modal windows are displayed but there you go, life is full of surprises.

Has anyone else observed the same behaviour?  Has anyone found a solution for it?

This is not a showstopper but it is certainly annoying.

Comment: sounds like the issue reported at https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk/issues/137#issuecomment-1986337278 ? not completely sure.